# Can a Pivot table transpose values

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Starting from a table like this:

```
Name    Grade   Subj    Course
Dave    9       Math    Algebra I
Dave    9       Eng     Eng I
Dave    9       Sci     Biology
Ed      10      Math    Algebra 2
Ed      10      Eng     Eng 2
Ed      10      Sci     Chemistry
Mary    9       Math    Algebra I
Mary    9       Eng     Eng I
Mary    9       Sci     Biology
```

I'd like to get a table like this:

```
Name    Grade   Math        Eng     Sci
Dave    9       Algebra I   Eng I   Biology
Ed      10      Algebra 2   Eng 2   Chemistry
Mary    9       Algebra I   Eng I   Biology
```

Where the values in the table are transposed from the original table rows?

If I use the tabular pivot table layout, I can get the name and the grade on 1 line, then I can get the subjects across the top by putting them in columns. The part I'm having trouble in is getting the course title in the actual cells.

When I put course title in values, it just gives me a count.

[what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kSeI.jpg)

Ok that answer runs a little fast for me. Here are the steps:

- Open your table in the Power Query editor

  - make the data into a table
  - select the table
  - select data -> from table/range
- Use Power Query to make the transposition

  - select the Subj and Course columns
  - Select the Transform tab:
  - Select Pivot Column, you may have to hover to find it
  - Values column = Course
  - Select advanced options -> don't aggregate
- Bring it back

  - Home Tab
  - Close and load ..

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/895916/excel-pivot-table-show-values-instead-of-summaries?rq=1

Comment: What you are trying as output is not possible using Transform since it shifts Row into Column to Row. Your output is like extracting Unique records. I can suggest you 2 steps solution will generate exact list like you shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Power Query to get the result:
[image]

Comment: That's good and solves 95% of what I need.  If Mary has 2 math classes, her math cell goes blank.  Any chance of putting something more meaningful?